Why dos my 12V adaptor give electric shock even when switched off?
Even when the mains supply is switched off but plugged in, my 12V adaptor gives electric shock, like small currents. Why?
This is my adaptor

And this is where I feel the shock


What adaptor? What part is the shock coming from? Could be leakage, could be just a cheap off brand crappy dangerous adaptor with certification markings that don't mean anything.

It is definitely a heap off brand adaptor. I don't know how to define dangerous. The shock is coming from its DC side, but only when it is plugged in (The switch is off). When I remove he plug, it doesn't shock.

Is this a static electric discharge?  Does the same happen when you touch other grounded things like the ground screw on the outlet?  The mains supply only disconnects the phase (hot) line, but the outlet still has connections to ground via the grounding wire and the neutral that could discharge static charge back to earth.

@BK303 I don't know what is static charge, but I have updated my question with some pictures. Please don't md my dog hair on the adaptor, I don't know how they got there.

Could you please give more details about what/where the adaptor output is connected to? Especially the 2nd picture.

@RohatKılıç It foes to a DC circuit for a pet project I have been building, but it doesn't matter, the wires still shock when I remove the circuit. I just now tested.

I just tested another adaptor and it is not giving the same shock. Why?

What switch are you talking about? Does your mains socket have a switch or where is this switch? On an extension cord?

@Justme Its the mains socket switch I am talking about.

Asked to verify if the shock was coming from the load or the adapter output. So it appears to be the adapter output. My wild guess would be that if the output DC negative is connected to the earth if there's no physical earth connection inside the building or if there's some sort of leakage then you may get an electric shock. The symbol on bottom left in the 1st photo looks like a "double insulation" logo but there may not be enough insulation.

@RohatKılıç That's a standard two prong wall wart. It is not earthed regardless of the building. The earth prong is plastic to open the safety latches for the two other prongs.

@Justme why is one adaptor giving shock and the other not? Is this a quality issue? What would be "Good Brands" for adaptors?

@Justme the earth prong looks shiny on my monitor. At first sight I thought it's a proper metal ground prong.

What likely happens is that your wall socket switch controls the mains neutral wire of the power supply.
When switch is off the mains live stil goes into power supply.
The power supply is a standard two-prong un-grounded switch mode power supply. It has a plastic earth prong used to open the safety covers of the neutral and live terminals.
Inside the switch mode power supply there is a so-called Y capacitor between mains side and low voltage side for EMI and EMC purposes.
And together with the mains socket being able to pass live only into supply and the capacitor being between live side and low voltage side then you get a shock through the capacitor.
The other power supply must have different internal design if it does not give a shock. It may be a linear transformer supply without Y cap or it may have grounded output.

Is either of the adaptor a danger to electronics?
